# How to efficiently save and retrieve City, Region, Country

Tags: database, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I need to save and lookup information regarding the `Place` of my database entities. `Place` can be either a *city*, *region* or *country*.

I am looking the most efficient solution to save and retrieve this information, both in terms of speed but also in development time.

I identified two viable options, but both have significant drawbacks.

1. **DYI Approach**: populate (and maintain) 3 tables, one for world
   cities, one for world regions and one for world countries. Cities would have foreign key reference to regions and regions to countries. If some countries do not have regions, I would simply link the city straight to the country. The problem with this approach is that Cities and Regions tables would be massive and simply impractical to maintain. Also I haven't found a good resource to populate the data in the first place..
2. **Rely on third party API**: another approach I thought about was to rely on the google place API. I could use the API to search for cities, regions and countries only and as a result I get a JSON in this format :

`{
    ...
    "geometry": {
     ...
    },
    "icon": "https://icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id": "3a4638f694c001b0aa4f710e9b7925bf914e4f56",
    "name": "Arco"
}`

As an option I thought I could ***save the google place id in my database***. This would make it very easy to store the information and retrieve all related data when needed. **But what if Google decides to change its ids**?

Are there any other options I am missing? Have you faced a similar issue? Are there workarounds to the outlined problems?